# Connection between SDN products and OpenStack

Tags: sdn, openstack-neutron

I've read about different SDN products such as openFlow. What I've got so far is that inside of the openstack project there is a part called Neutron that is a stub for managing networking in a system. For example openFlow can work as a plugin in neutron, and actually apply the wanted functionality to the network. But openFlow can also work alone, and if within the openstack is it different? I want to understand more specifically the connection between these two.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your questions, entirely, but does this link answer it for you: http://wikibon.org/wiki/v/SDN,_OpenFlow_and_OpenStack_Quantum

Comment: Or here: http://www.buildyourbestcloud.com/131/how-does-neutron-relate-openflow

Answer (score 0):

OpenStack is a set of software tools for building and managing cloud computing platforms for public and private clouds. The cloud is all about providing computing for end users in a remote environment, where the actual software runs as a service on reliable and scalable servers rather than on each end users computer. 
OpenStack is considered Infrastructure as a Service (IaaS). Providing infrastructure means that OpenStack makes it easy for users to quickly add new instance, upon which other cloud components can run. Typically, the infrastructure then runs a "platform" upon which a developer can create software applications which are delivered to the end users.
OpenFlow is an Open Networking Foundation initiative that does not embody SDN completely, but is instead an open protocol that provides communication between the control and data (or forwarding) planes of the routing component in a network. This component can be either a physical router or switch, or a virtual hypervisor-based router. The current version of OpenFlow is 1.4, although many vendors and providers support versions as far back as 1.0.

References: 
Neutron Openstack (http://docs.openstack.org/havana/install-guide/install/yum/content/install-neutron.html)
Openflow: http://archive.openflow.org/wk/index.php/OpenFlow_Wiki